# How to watch c++ STL collections in NetBeans 8.1 debugger with cygwin toolchain?

Tags: debugging, stl, cygwin, netbeans-8

I'd like to see elements of vector in NetBeans with cygwin toolchain. There are some instructions, but it is not clear how to apply them to cygwin. Did anyone have positive experience with it?

Thanx.

Comment: Hope this can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDJ7YhMzsXw

Comment: No, this is not related to STL collections watching in debugger, this is only setup which work off the box now.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, with Netbeans 8.2 and cygwin64:

- check if libstdc++ is installed (using cygwin 'setup-x86_64.exe')
- download the scripts at
      https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python/libstdcxx
- copy all folders and files including folder 'libstdcxx' to cygwin. For example:
      c:\bin\cygwin64\usr\share\gdb\python
  (after copying, there should be a file 'printers.py' at the folder:
      c:\bin\cygwin64\usr\share\gdb\python\libstdcxx\v6
- open Netbeans project properties/debug and check where it's looking for the Gdb ini file (mine is at c:\users\MYUSER\.gdbinit)
- create a file .gdbinit at that folder, containing:
      python
      import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\bin\cygwin64\usr\share\gdb\python')
  from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
  register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
  end

  (attention to the correct sys.path.insert above)
- rebuild your project. When debugging, the 'Variables' tab will show meaningful info.